# Get CWD of bjobs in LSF environment

Tags: lsf

bjobs -l  gives the long description of the job where CWD is split across say 3 lines.
I want a command that can reliable fetch me CWD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a recent version of LSF (9.1.2+ I believe), you can use the `-o` option of `bjobs` to customize the bjobs short form output to give you each job's CWD on a single line:

```
$ bjobs -o 'jobid exec_cwd' 5950
JOBID EXEC_CWD
5950  /home/squirrel/cwd
```

If you're running an older version of LSF your only real option is to parse the long form bjobs output.

The `-UF` option to `bjobs` will display the same output at the `-l` option, but in an "unformatted" way.  This will basically take all of those job events that are currently split into many lines and display each one on a single line for easier parsing.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am currently using older version.